# How to read information from bank cheque using Tesseract?

Tags: c#, tesseract

I have a sample cheque. I am trying to read the following

a) Branch Name (i.e. Salwa Branch)

b) Doha on (i.e. 1/7/2016)

c) Pay against this cheque to/order

d) Riyals

e) QR

f) Cheque No.

I am using Tesseract. What extra thing I need to do for getting the relevant info since I am not able to get the informations properly.

Or any other OCR SDK is there specific to this purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handwritten values are not possible to detect with tesseract. Although there is a possibility to [train tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract) for the User fonts, that won't help in your case as cheques may not be of same handwriting.

But still, you can get the values for printed characters such as branch name, Cheque no.s etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is hand written, will not be accepted in any way. You have only chances with known or similar fonts. In your case i would analyse the complete image/tiff and than go through all blocks that are created with Tesseract.

Comment: If you can't OCR handwritten text, how can software like [Microsoft Ink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698602(v=vs.85).aspx) work? It's not a difficult problem, but I wouldn't say "unacceptable in any way".

Comment: It is absolutely possible, but not using Tesseract like this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I've never used Tesseract. My bad- I thought you were saying handwriting recognition was categorically impossible. Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

is easy with tesseract.

Use this .net wrapper works very well.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/

Examples can be found on his project page.

In same cases you have to train the fonts. How you can read here:

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/a-guide-on-ocr-with-tesseract-3-03/

For Number and symbols (middle bottom) is a trained font available I found by google for tesseract.